# Oracle: counting sum of flags between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:
The first one contains the beginning and the end of an interval:

```
------------------------------
DATE_START   |   DATE_END
------------------------------
2020-01-04       2023-07-04
------------------------------
```

The second one is the calendar with dates and boolean "special day" indicator:

```
------------------------------
DATE         |   SPECIAL_DAY_FLAG
------------------------------
2020-01-04       1
------------------------------
2020-01-05       0
------------------------------
```

So I need a query, that returns only rows from the first table, where number of "special days" between DATE_START and DATE_END is greater than 14.

Comment: is there no other key to join the tables ?

Comment: nope, only dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join to your second table (which I've called 'calendar') based on the date range from the first table (which I've called 'intervals'); filter those joined records on the flag value, and count how many matches there are; and finally use `having` to check the count is 14 or more:

```
select i.date_start, i.date_end,
  count(c.calendar_date) as special_days
from intervals i
join calendar c on c.calendar_date >= i.date_start and c.calendar_date <= i.date_end
where c.special_day_flag = 1
group by i.date_start, i.date_end
having count(c.calendar_date) >= 14
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2SKqdoVN)

... where I've assumed the interval is inclusive - if it isn't then change to `< end_date`.

---

If you wanted to count total matched days as well as special days you could also use conditional aggregation; which would need to be in a subquery to then filter by number of special days.